# Add multiple users to multiple groups from one import csv

Tags: powershell, import, active-directory, bulk, active-directory-group

I have a csv with 2 columns, one column is AD group names and one is user account names. I am trying to read the csv and import the users into their corresponding group.

Here is what i have to so far. It's saying both arguments(identity,member) are null, which makes no sense since the headers are correctly specified.

```
import-module activedirectory
$list = import-csv "C:\Scripts\Import Bulk Users into bulk groups\bulkgroups3.csv"

Foreach($user in $list){       
    add-adgroupmember -identity $_.Group -member $_.Accountname
}
```

Heres whats in the csv file

```
Group             Accountname 
group1            user1 
group1            user2 
group1            user3 
group2            user4 
group2            user5 
group3            user6 
group3            user7 
group3            user8 
group4            user9 
group5            user10
```

**EDIT** Command and error

Here is my script, error i receive and csv.

```
Import-Csv "C:\Scripts\Import Bulk Users into bulk groups\bulkgroups.csv" | 
ForEach { get-aduser $_.Accountname | add-adgroupmember $_.Group}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: you specifically called the current object for `$user` in your foreach loop, so take a look at EBGreen's answer. Also, for future questions. It would be nice if you included a sample of the CSV-file so we know ex. what delimiter you are using.

Comment: I tried to add the csv but i did not see an option to insert attachment. the layout below is all i have in the CSV file which is 2 columns.I do not know if i know what a delimiter is. Is this the seperation between objects in the csv? In that case it would just be the | in each row.

Comment: Yes, it's the seperator. Open the csv file in notepad to see it's content and it's delimiter. Then you could have included that instead of the one above : ) No need now, but just a tip. Excel(or similar software) displays it in rows, but CSV are pure textfiles with rows as lines and columns seperated by a delimiter(often `,` or `;` )

Answer (score 7):

Change this:

```
add-adgroupmember -identity $_.Group -member $_.Accountname
```

To this:

```
add-adgroupmember -identity $user.Group -member (Get-ADUser $user.Accountname)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I made the changes and it looks like it is pulling the correct information from the csv, but now it i get " cannot find object with identity under:dc=domain,dc=com". Here is another part to this question. If i run the command get-aduser or add-adgroupmember for a single user, it finds the ad object and works fine, but if i add foreach or foreach-object, it no longer fines the user/object in AD and i am trying to understand why this is. Do i need to specify a searchscope when using foreach?

Comment: I am a dumb idiot. i had a space after all the account names. sigghhhh. That would explain why get-qaduser worked, because it uses a wildcard unless you specify -samaccountname. so nothing was wrong with your scripts. it was all my fault and again i really appreciate all your help. I did have one more easy question if you dont mind. Does get-aduser use a wildcard when you specify an account? i have ambiguous accounts in my domain such as c42q, c42q1234. Would i need to add anything to get-aduser to make sure it only adds c42q to a group?

Comment: It does not default to wildcarding. To use wildcards you have yo explicitly use a -Filter block

Answer (score 2):

@EBGreen has answered what's wrong with your code. Just coming up with an alternative here. Instead of running the command once per member, you can try to add all members of a group at the same time. The `Member` parameter supports an array, so try this:

```
Import-Csv "C:\Scripts\Import Bulk Users into bulk groups\bulkgroups3.csv" | Group-Object Group | % {
    #Foreach Group, get ADUser object for users and add members
    $users = $_.Group | % { Get-ADUser $_.Accountname }
    Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $_.Name -Member $users
}
```

**EDIT** I've sucessfully tested this on 2012 DC with following content in test.csv (values represent existing group name and existing samaccountname/username):

```
Group,Accountname
"Mytestgroup","kim_akers"
"Mytestgroup","user1"
```

**EDIT2** It shouldn't have any problems with deeper level OUs. I tested with an OU that was 7 levels deep and it had no problem. If you have all the user inside one OU (or find the closest OU that contains all the sub-OUs), see if this script helps. Remember to replace DN for "base OU" in `-Searchbase` parameter.

```
Import-Csv "C:\Scripts\Import Bulk Users into bulk groups\bulkgroups3.csv" | Group-Object Group | % {
    #Foreach Group, get ADUser object for users and add members
    $users = $_.Group | % { Get-ADUser -Searchbase "OU=mybaseou,OU=test,OU=users,OU=contoso,DC=Contoso,DC=com" -Filter { samaccountname -eq $_.Accountname } }
    Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $_.Name -Member $users
}
```

Comment: see updated answer. Also, please provide copy of script when you provide pictures of error. ex. you said that you recieved errors earlier from my script, when you were actually using a non-functional pipeline command. So if I'm gonna have any chance of helping you, I will always need script and exception(you can just copy the text into a codeblock instead of pictures). ;-) using codeblocks instead of pictures would also help covering sensitive info, as I can see in the pictures that you're netbios domain name is "ifb", which limits down the potential domainnames, hehe.

Comment: Note, however, that apparently this breaks if the collection passed as an argument to the **-Members** parameter has too many members: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21226365/add-multiple-users-to-multiple-groups-from-one-import-csv-follow-up-query/21227293?noredirect=1#comment32009715_21227293

Comment: It's not because it has too many members. It because it tries to add the whole collection in one run. The cmdlet breaks/cancels when you try to add a user that already exists, so as soon as it detects a user in the collection that's already a member in the group, it aborts the whole operation(= no users added). The solution is to run the command once per user in the collection, as you've figured out.

Comment: That's what I mean. I don't mean a limitation of AD on the number of members in a group; my solution of adding the members one at a time wouldn't make sense if that were the case. In fact, an AD group can have millions of members. I mean a limitation on the number of members in the *collection* or array passed as an argument that **Add-ADGroupMember** can process at once.

Comment: No, the is no limit in how big the collection argument can be. This would happend with a collection of 1, 2 or even 1000 members. The problem is that when you're passing a collection like `$users`, it adds them at the same time, so if everything is not perfect for every member in the collection it cancels it all. This would happend even with 2 members in the collection if at least one of them was already a member. If you/I had removed every existing member from `$users` before running `ad-adgroupmember -members $users`, you could add thousands without any problem.