# Add multiple users to multiple groups from one import csv (follow up query)

Tags: powershell, csv, import, active-directory, bulk

I was looking for a way to populate multiple distribution groups with multiple user names. I came across [a script on this site written by member Frode F.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16651580/add-multiple-users-to-multiple-groups-from-one-import-csv#new-answer?newreg=49d4e98054ae4ec7aa6761c0aa7d354e):

```
Import-Csv "C:\Scripts\Import Bulk Users into bulk groups\bulkgroups3.csv" | Group-Object Group | % {
    #Foreach Group, get ADUser object for users and add members
    $users = $_.Group | % { Get-ADUser $_.Accountname }
    Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $_.Name -Member $users
}
```

This was working when the csv file contained about 10 lines with 2 different groups in column 1 and multiple users in column 2.
When the csv contains a few hundred lines, still only 2 groups it fails to populate the groups at all. These are the errors:

```
Add-ADGroupMember : The specified account name is already a member of the group
At C:\scripts\AddUsersDistributionGroups.ps1:6 char:22
+     Add-ADGroupMember <<<<  -Identity $_.Name -Member $users
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Group A:ADGroup) [Add-ADGroupMember], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : The specified account name is already a member of the group,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.AddADGroupMember

Add-ADGroupMember : The specified account name is already a member of the group
At C:\scripts\AddUsersDistributionGroups.ps1:6 char:22
+     Add-ADGroupMember <<<<  -Identity $_.Name -Member $users
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Group B:ADGroup) [Add-ADGroupMember], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : The specified account name is already a member of the group,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.AddADGroupMember
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the answer you're referring to? Also, I believe @username only works in comments, not in questions and answers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16651580/add-multiple-users-to-multiple-groups-from-one-import-csv#new-answer?newreg=49d4e98054ae4ec7aa6761c0aa7d354e

Comment: Note that the script you quoted was actually from Frode F.'s answer, not EBGreen's. I added the link to your question and corrected the attribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps there's a limit to how many members **Add-ADGroupMember** can handle at once, and it croaks if you pass the **-Members** parameter a collection of hundreds? Instead of grouping all the users into a collection, try adding them one at a time:

```
Import-Csv "C:\Scripts\Import Bulk Users into bulk groups\bulkgroups3.csv" | %{
    Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $_.Group -Members $_.Accountname
}
```

This assumes that the values in the **Group** and **Accountname** columns are valid identity properties--which they'd have to be in order for the script you quoted to work. Note, though, that this script will take a long time to run, because the AD cmdlets usually execute slowly, and you'll be executing **Add-ADGroupMember** once per user (i.e., per line in the CSV file) rather than once per group. You might find it useful to add a line to the **Foreach-Object** block indicating progress so that you know it's working rather than getting stuck.

Comment: You're right on the money, there must be a limitation to how many members can be handled at once. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Hi, I am now getting the error "Get-ADGroupMember : Cannot find an object with identity:" for any new groups. These groups are in AD

Comment: Would it help to include the location of the groups OU in the script? The error "Add-ADGroupMember : Cannot find an object with identity: 'GroupName' under: 'DC=domain,DC=local'." states the search is from the top level of the domain. Would it help to expand the search e.g. 'OU=container,OU=container,DC=domain,DC=local'?

Comment: I don't think so, since it already searches the entire directory by default. When its says `under: 'DC=domain,DC=local'`, it means the entire subtree beginning at that node. It sounds like some of the values in the **Group** column don't match valid identity attributes for any existing groups.

Comment: There appears to be a limitation with the amount of spaces in the group name. e.g. group name 'All Staff' works, 'All Staff NSW' will not. Any ideas other than removing the spacing?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem with adding multiple members via the Add-ADGroupMember and I think I found the solution. Thought I'd share it for posterity.

It has nothing to do with limitations on the number of members that can be handled....the cmdlet can handle thousands.

The issue is that the list of members passed via the -MEMBERS argument cannot have duplicates. If there are duplicates in that list then we get the error above.

The resolution? Either pass clean data without dupes or use the foreach argument to pass one member at a time.