# Add multiple users to multiple groups from one import csv (another follow up)

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

First I have to say I've [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21226365/add-multiple-users-to-multiple-groups-from-one-import-csv-follow-up-query) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16651580/add-multiple-users-to-multiple-groups-from-one-import-csv) thread already, but couldn't figure out an answer from those.

I have a CSV file looking like this:

```
Username,Groups
User01,Group01;Group02;Group03
User02,Group10;Group24;Group08
User03,Group13;Group02;Group42
```

etc etc... There are hundreds of users and hundreds of different groups in total, so splitting individual users and/or groups to their own lines manually is not really an option.

I cannot figure out the logic how to process the lines with foreach while splitting the imported CSV *twice* with different delimiters and then foreach the groups per user *again*. Any ideas..?

Comment: Please can you clarify what you are trying to do with the data from this CSV file? The description of your problem is a little confusing as it explains more about what you don't think will work rather than clearly explaining what you are trying to do. Thanks.

Comment: I'm trying to bulk-add users to AD groups, as in User01 to Group01, Group02 and Group03, then User02 to Group10, Group24 and Group08 etc.

Comment: Is the CSV format always like that (Username, Groups) or does the format of the file vary?

Comment: I could change the comma delimiter and replace the semicolons I guess, but for the argument's sake let's say that's the formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split groups on `;` character, so if you want add users to groups use this:

```powershell
$src = Import-Csv yourfile.csv
foreach($line in $src){
    $user = $line.Username
    $groups = $line.Groups -split ";"
    foreach($group in $groups){
        Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Members $user
        # other code which uses $group and $user
    }
}
```

Comment: This did it, thanks! Using split saves from having to parse each group listed in the cell again. Apparently I was thinking this way too complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like

```
$Line = import-csv yourfile.csv
#Skip first line here
 foreach ($Data in $Line)
 {
  $User = $Data.v1
  $Group1 = $Data.v2
  $Group2 = $Data.v3
  $Group3 = $Data.v4

  write-host "User: "$User
  write-host "Group1: "$Group1
  write-host "Group2: "$Group2
  write-host "Group3: "$Group3
  Write-Host ""
 }
```

Comment: Uh, am I missing something here..? I'm working with PowerShell on this one.

Comment: Sorry, was in PHP mode for another problem.