# Export Groups and Member SamAccountName or DisplayName to CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

I'm having some issues importing group and membership data from the CSV I had created, the reason is because the export I am doing is exporting the member's `CN` name instead of the `SamAccountName` or `DisplayName` that the import requires.

Currently my exported CSV looks like this:

```
"name","Members"
"GROUP1","CN=LEEROY JENKINS,OU=ADMINISTRATORS,OU=USERS,OU=DOMAIN,DC=DOMAIN,DC=LOCAL;CN=MICHAEL JACKSON,OU=ADMINISTRATORS,OU=USERS,OU=DOMAIN,DC=DOMAIN,DC=LOCAL;CN=JERRY SPRINGER,OU=GUESTS,OU=USERS,OU=DOMAIN,DC=DOMAIN,DC=LOCAL" 
"GROUP2","CN=KIMMY SHMIDT,OU=ADMINISTRATORS,OU=USERS,OU=DOMAIN,DC=DOMAIN,DC=LOCAL;CN=MICHAEL JACKSON,OU=ADMINISTRATORS,OU=USERS,OU=DOMAIN,DC=DOMAIN,DC=LOCAL;CN=JERRY SPRINGER,OU=GUESTS,OU=USERS,OU=DOMAIN,DC=DOMAIN,DC=LOCAL"
```

Which I got from executing:

```
Get-ADGroup -SearchBase "ou=groups,ou=DOMAIN,dc=DOMAIN,dc=local" -Properties name,members -Filter * |
    select members, name |
    Export-Csv BLAH.CSV -NoTypeInformation
```

I think I am left with two issues, one being that the import won't take the CN as a valid member name and also not sure whether it will work with each group having multiple users.

On a side note - I found [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16651580/add-multiple-users-to-multiple-groups-from-one-import-csv). Similar issue, however, I haven't got as far as he has with the nicely formatted table of 'Group1 - Name1'. I'm basically trying to figure out an automatic way to create a table with the groupname and membership details that can be imported into Active Directory.

Comment: You want to use the data to add the members of your csv to the adgroups referenced?

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same problem, and for me it was because groups have multiple members, and PowerShell doesn't handle the 1:M relationship well. I started using this to pull group members:

```
(Get-ADGroupMember -Identity GroupName -Recursive | select name | Out-String).Trim()
```

As that puts all of the group members into one cell. Note that Excel has a size limit on the number of characters in a single cell, so if you have a group with thousands of members, it will error out on you. I'm sure that there are better ways, that is just what works for me.

You could pipe your current script into it, ie:

Edited to more closely match what you need:

```
$Groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter {YOURFILTER} | select -ExpandProperty sAmAccountname
foreach($Group in $Groups)
{
$Members = (Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group | select sAmAccountName | out-string).Trim() 

New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property @{
Users = $Members
Name = $Group
} | Export-Csv C:\Export.csv
}
```

Just make sure to expand the cells vertically to actually see the group members.